# Reusing code between different event handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one code block which I want to invoke in different scenarios when a click is triggered, depending on whether the event is direct or is delegated.

But on changing the code to `on`, it only works partially.

I have one code:

```
$(document).on('click','.selected-option',function(event){
//lot of code
```

I want to use:

```
$('.selected-option').click(function(event){ //lots of code  }
```

I want to use this together like:

```
if (some condition)
{
    $(document).on('click','.selected-option',function(event){
}
else   
{
    $('.selected-option').click(function(event){
}
```

and want to use the same code.

Comment: Don't those two lines both attach a `click` listener to `.selected-option`? If so, why not put the condition inside your function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't *have* to use anonymous functions to handle events. Just write a regular function:

```
function handleClick(event) {
  // lots of code
}
```

Then bind the function to as many events as you want:

```
if (some condition) {
  $(document).on('click','.selected-option', handleClick);  
else {
  $('.selected-option').click(handleClick);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

define a function and do the job;

```
var funCalled = function(){
    //your detailed actions
}
```

and call it in different conditions!

```
if (some condition) {
    $(document).on('click','.selected-option',function(event){
        funCalled()
    })
} else {
    $('.selected-option').click(function(event){
        funCalled()
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var testfunction = function(currentObj){
  // your code here
}   

 if (some condition)
  {
      $(document).on('click','.selected-option',function(event){
          testfunction($(this));  
      });
  }
 else {
      $('.selected-option').click(function(event){
          testfunction($(this));  
       });
  }
```